# Ubuntu Touch webapp icon

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, icons, webapps

Why not change my webapp icon for 'ubuntu-touch' after updating? Apparently it is properly updated in the app store, but when I install it, no.
I've created the icon following this guide >> https://design.ubuntu.com/apps/style/iconography

Comment: did you try restarting the phone? also What is your webapp? tell us, maybe it will work on another phone. (pictures may help in this case, you can still upload to imigur.com and paste links to have them edited in by another user)

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting the phone. My webapp's name is "mendiApp". It's a webapp stored in cloud for firefoxOS.

Comment: ah, I see - you need to reprogram the app, and replace it's icon - it doesn't use the stores icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon for the store, and the icon in the package are separate:

You need to change the icon out within your click package, there should be a icon within the package, and a reference to it in the `.desktop` file as shown:

[image]

(Picture of a webapp package within the Ubuntu SDK)

So replace the .png file and if the name changes be sure to change the name where it says "Icon="